# Installing a plugin from python

Tags: python, pip

I'm creating a plugin loader in python, and each plugin has a requirements.txt file in the folder. I would like the plugin loader to be able to install the requirements, before running the plugin. It iterates through the requirements.txt, and runs `os.system("pip install {}".format(rq))`, but this doesn't work on Windows, when PATH isn't set. I want this program to be able to run on computers without pip in path. Is this possible?

Comment: First of all, **never ever** use `os.system`, especially not like that. You are inviting your user to be hacked with that. Second, look up `sys.exectuable`

Comment: What you describe sounds a lot like [a package's *extras*](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#optional-dependencies), e.g. ``pip install mypackage[plugin_a,another_plugin]``. You probably should not re-invent that wheel.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, each plugin can have a requirement such as "discord.py" in the requirements.txt file. It isn't for separate plugin packages.